# submit inside submit

Tags: jquery

I admit its not very clear title. But I did not know how else to name what I am trying to do.

I have index.htm. this page pulls data from index.asp?Process=ViewRequests with the following code.

```
    $(function Requests() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'content/requests/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewRequests',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#requests").html(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#requests").html('.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Then, in this new pulled data set, I have a few forms. All forms have REQUESTFORM as ID and submit buttons' name is respond. What I need it needs to perform; once user clicks on either of these forms, clicked form should send its data to index.asp?Process=RespondRequests and print its response.

```
    $("[name='respond']").click(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#REQUESTFORM").serialize(),
                url: "content/requests/index.cs.asp?Process=RespondRequests", 
                success: function(output) { 
                $('#REQUESTFORM').html(output)
                },
                error: function(output) {
                $('#REQUESTFORM').html(output);
                }
            }); 
    });
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have more than one element with the same ID, or at least you won't be able to use the ID for anything useful if you do. But since the submit button is below the form tag, you can use the `closest` function to select the closest form. And since `this` within a click event refers to the element being clicked you can easily get a hold of the form for the button clicked:

```
   $(function Requests() {
     $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'content/requests/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewRequests',
       success: function(data) {
         var that = this;
         $("#requests").html(data);
         $("[name='respond']").click(function() { 
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: $(that).closest("form").serialize(),
             url: "content/requests/index.cs.asp?Process=RespondRequests", 
             success: function(output) { 
               $(that).closest("form").html(output)
             },
             error: function(output) {
               $(that).closest("form").html(output);
             }
           });
         });
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $("#requests").html('.');
       }
     });
   });
```

Comment: hi, I tried the code, I did not receive any error but it did not work. Any idea?

Comment: This code is your code copy pased together with the addition of this, that and closest. Try to add alerts here and there, maybe in the click function and see if they show. Also verify that all the selectors work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure of what are you trying to do but you can use the submit event for the form and handle the request by AJAX. In the handler function you should return false to prevent the form to be submited in the browser (because you will submit it by AJAX).

I hope it helps.